# Differentiate the Function: $f(x)=\ln (\sin^2x)$

Tags: calculus

$$\begin{align}f(x)&=\ln (\sin^2x)\\
f'(x)&=\frac{1}{\sin^2x}\cdot 2(\sin x)(\cos x)\\
&=\frac{2(\sin x)(\cos x)}{\sin^2x}\\
&=\frac{2\ \ (\cos x)\ }{\sin x}\\
&=2\cot x
\end{align}$$
= $2\ cot\ x$

Is this answer right?

Comment: Not clear where you get the $\sin^2 x$ in the numerator.

Comment: Thomas - The $sin^2 x$ is calculated due to $ \frac{d}{dx}\ lin\ x= \frac{1}{x}$

Comment: Why was I down voted?

Comment: That explains the $\sin^2 x$ in the denominator, not the second $\sin^2 x$ in the first line of the computation of $f'(x)$.  As for the downvote, it is possible the person doesn't like the formatting that I did (or didn't like the format before.)

Comment: Yeah I see what I did wrong.

Comment: Now you've cancelled wrong at the last step.

Comment: I just fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} (\sin^2 x) = 2 \sin x \cos x.$$

We get, using the chain rule that$$f'(x) = \frac{2 \sin x \cos x}{\sin^2 x}$$

Our derivative simplifies to $$f'(x) = 2 \cot x.$$

Comment: So the only part I was failed to do was converting the $2\ sinx\ cosx$ into $2\ cotx$

Comment: No, no. $\frac{2 \sin x \cos x}{\sin ^2 x}$, one $\sin x$ cancels leaving us with $\frac{2 \cos x}{\sin x} = 2 \cot x$

Comment: I see it know. Thanks.

Comment: Great! No problem. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Not quite; you have misapplied the Chain Rule. If $f(x) = g(h(x))$, where here $g(x) = \ln x$ and $h(x) = \sin^2 x$, then $f'(x) = g'(h(x))h'(x)$, so we get
$$
  \frac{1}{\sin^2 x}\cdot\frac{d}{dx}(\sin^2 x) = \frac{2\sin x\cos x}{\sin^2 x}
     = \frac{2\cos x}{\sin x} = 2\cot x.
$$